# Matlab fitting two curves with different variables for constant

Tags: matlab

Hi i have data in the form of two column vectors (z,y) which forms an exponential curve.

And I want to find 1 unknown for it by fitting a curve of the form i.e. solve for b in the equation

```
y=  (1-0.05*x^(b))/(1-0.05*x^b)^2
```

I want to solve for `b` which gives a good fit for `data (z,y)` however the only known parameter is `z` and `y`. Is there possible way I could solve for `b`? any tips on how to proceed with this equation? The `x` values are unknown and `x` seem to be the main problem!

Thanks!

Comment: So... does `y= (1-0.05*x^b).^-2`? I don't uderstand the relationship between `z` and `y` or `z` and `x`? If you have (`x`,`y`) data then you can solve for `b` (OLS regrssion for example). But if all you have is (`z`,`y`) data and no relationship between `z` and `x` then I can't see how this is possible

Comment: Yeah i do know a particular range for x but its a rough estimate i.e. x typically ranges from 1-5 as a function of y. And i have data for y. I guess it could give me a rough estimate for b...